# error while Linking c++ and ns2?

Tags: c++, ns2

had done following steps
 Download "ex-linkage.cc" file, and save it under the "ns-2" directory. 
Open "Makefile", add "ex-linkage.o" at the end of object file list.

Re-compile NS using the "make" command. Download the "ex-linkage.tcl" file

that contains "MyAgent" testing OTcl commands.

Run the OTcl script using command "ns ex-linkage.tcl".

---

i am getting following error

```
$ ./ns ex-linkage.tcl
invalid command name "Agent/MyAgentOtcl" 
    while executing 
"Agent/MyAgentOtcl create o3 " 
    invoked from within 
"catch "$className create $o $args" msg" 
    invoked from within 
"if [catch "$className create $o $args" msg] { 
if [string match "__FAILED_SHADOW_OBJECT" $msg] { 
delete $o 
return "" 
} 
global errorInfo 
error "class $..." 
    (procedure "new" line 3) 
    invoked from within 
"new Agent/MyAgentOtcl" 
    invoked from within 
"set myagent [new Agent/MyAgentOtcl]" 
    (file "ex-linkage.tcl" line 8
```

Comment: Questions asking for tutorials are off-topic for SO.

Comment: im not asking for a full flow tutorial i am just asking for a some hints which will direct me to the linking process of c++ and ns2

Comment: i had already tried many methods that available over internet but since i am new to ns2 programming i couldn't make full use of it

Comment: i even read ebooks https://books.google.co.in/books?id=_VkTzFLnwD4C&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=steps+to+link+ns2+and+c%2B%2B&source=bl&ots=__06kn9sok&sig=MWyzBwFvIseA05TACluZvLidsfc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwA2oVChMIoLHcqciMyQIVj3COCh0Jlg7Z#v=onepage&q=steps%20to%20link%20ns2%20and%20c%2B%2B&f=false

Comment: Explain what did you try and how do you fail. Show errors you get if you don't understand them. Ask specific questions and you will get answers.

Comment: i had done following steps 
    Download "ex-linkage.cc" file, and save it under the "ns-2" directory.
    Open "Makefile", add "ex-linkage.o" at the end of object file list.
    Re-compile NS using the "make" command.
    Download the "ex-linkage.tcl" file that contains "MyAgent" testing OTcl commands. (see Figure 22 for the input script and the result)
    Run the OTcl script using command "ns ex-linkage.tcl".

Comment: i am getting following error $ ./ns ex-linkage.tcl
invalid command name "Agent/MyAgentOtcl"
    while executing
"Agent/MyAgentOtcl create _o3 "
    invoked from within
"catch "$className create $o $args" msg"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$className create $o $args" msg] {
if [string match "__FAILED_SHADOW_OBJECT_" $msg] {
delete $o
return ""
}
global errorInfo
error "class $..."
    (procedure "new" line 3)
    invoked from within
"new Agent/MyAgentOtcl"
    invoked from within
"set myagent [new Agent/MyAgentOtcl]"
    (file "ex-linkage.tcl" line 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

»» invalid command name "Agent/MyAgentOtcl" «« : Looks like you are using an executable 'ns' with no "Linkage".

```
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc482.tar.gz
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSGJCZ2YzUGJDVk0/view?usp=sharing

```
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
patch -p0 < linkage_ns235.patch
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNYmZ0SWFQaUNhWTA/view?usp=sharing

```
./install
cd ns-2.35/
sudo make install
cp ns ns235-linkage
sudo cp ns235-linkage /usr/local/bin/

Simulation : ns235-linkage ex-linkage.tcl
.
warning: no class variable Agent/MyAgentOtcl::my_var2_otcl
.
Message From MyPrivFunc
     my_var1 = 2
     my_var2 = 3.140000
```

Using the "ns235-linkage" command makes sure you are using the right 'ns'.
**P.S. :** You are not recompiling with 'make', but with 'make clean && make'. Or by running './install' in the top directory ns-allinone-2.35/.

---

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)[linkage-ns2](/questions/tagged/linkage-ns2)

Comment: is these steps possible in windows  i am using it under cygwin

Comment: when i try patch it shows 'patch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: i had downloaded a patch.exe and set it path still error persisit

Comment: i finally got some code which will be working but when compilling cpp code it shows dynamic loading is not supported in this environment does cygwin supports dynamic loading

Answer (score 0):

---

OK, Cygwin. ( Why hide important information http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html ).

The patch command : Install 'patch' , or install the 'Developer tools' if available.

You can use the {ns-2.35/} that comes with ns-allinone-2.35_gcc482.tar.gz ,,, and use the otherwise Cygwin installed {tcl8, tk8, otcl, tclcl}.

Besides that, the patch is just containing the two files ex-linkage.*, and a line for Makefile.in . The patch is supposed to make things easier.

Using : Make a copy of "linkage_ns235.patch" in the folder where you keep ns-2.35/, and do `$ patch -p0 < linkage_ns235.patch`

---

[cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin)

Comment: i tried patch.exe and it shows me hung up when i used patch -i and promted command line when used-p0 what else can be done

Answer (score 0):

---

OK, no working patch function in your cygwin, it seems.

May be your previously setup was OK, and you just have to recompile :

```
$ cd ns-2.35/ && make clean && make
```

---

Comment: thank you i switch from cygwin to ubuntu and it worked sucessfully

Comment: does it work for all cpp tcl code do we need to do any additional changes in the code

Comment: »» does it work for all cpp tcl code «« : Not understandable. What do you mean by "it" ? ...... Please elaborate. .

Comment: i tried another code in which we are trying to communicate from tcl to c and vice versa i set a value for a variable in c using tcl and calling that function worked successfully but when i tried to bind the function it shows numerous errors

Comment: `set myagent [new Agent/MyAgentOtcl]
$myagent set my_var1_otcl 67 
$myagent set my_var2_otcl 3.14 
$myagent call-my-priv-func
$myagent showvars `in this line i am getting errors
   ` invoked from within
"_o3 cmd showvars"
    invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
    (procedure "_o3" line 2)
    (SplitObject unknown line 2)
    invoked from within
"$myagent showvars"
    (file "agent.tcl" line 9)`